# use of Tanh() in the output layer of generator network

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, convolution

I am studying Generative Adversarial Networks. Recently, while reading a paper of Radford et al. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06434.pdf), I found that the output layer of their generator network uses Tanh(). The range of Tanh() is (-1, 1), however, pixel values of an image in double-precision format lies in [0, 1]. Can someone please explain why Tanh() is used in the output layer and how the generator generates images with proper pixel values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code of the paper, you will see that the authors preprocess the images: https://github.com/soumith/dcgan.torch/blob/master/data/donkey_folder.lua#L68 so that the values of the images are taken in `[-1, 1]`.

Then, in the generation part, they rescale the images to values in `[0, 1]`: https://github.com/soumith/dcgan.torch/blob/master/generate.lua#L89.